# Already stucked for 1 week in a basic analysis problem: Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, when $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = l > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I already stucked in a basic analysis problem for 1 week:

**when $ a_n > 0 \enspace ( n = 1 , 2 , \ldots )$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = l > 1$.
Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.**

I had found an answer on web.

But in the answer I found, there is one step I don't understand:

(I quote the answer in 3 blocks below and the second block $0<a_n<a_{N+1}{(\frac 1 r )}^{n-N-1}$ doesn't make sense to me. I don't know how to derive it.)

> Pick $r$, let $1 < r < l$. Because $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}= l > 1,$$
> we know: $$\exists N , \forall n > N: \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}>r>1 $$

> so we have  $$0<a_n<a_{N+1}{\left(\frac 1 r \right)}^{n-N-1}$$

> Because of $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{a_{N+1}{\left(\frac 1 r \right)}^{n-N-1}\right\}=0$$
> then we know $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$$

Can you please tell me a new way to solve this question or explain me why the second block in the answer I quoted make sense.
Thank you!

Comment: Use induction on $n$.

Comment: *Hint:* $a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\cdot  \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \cdots \frac{a_{N+2}}{a_{N+1}} \cdot a_{N+1}$

Comment: @MartinR Thank you! I use the hint , $a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \cdots \frac{a_{N+2}}{a_{N+1}} \cdot a_{N+1} $ ,which you gave , solved this question.  The hint is  wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n + 1}} \to \ell > 1$$
means that $(a_n)$ is decreasing when $n$ is big enough and because it's positive we deduce that $(a_n)$ converges. Let $a = \lim a_n$.
We have :
$$a_n = \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n + 1}} a_{n + 1}$$
then when $n \to +\infty$ :
$$a = \ell a$$
and because $\ell \neq 1$ we conclude that $a = 0$.

Comment: I think I am confused at a important part of your solution: how can we deduce that $(a_n)$converges from "$(a_n)$ is decreasing when n is big enougth and because it's positive" ?  In other words, how can we make sure that the limit of {$a_n$} exist then we can let $ a = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n $?  Can you explain more details? Thank you!!

Comment: It's a theorem : if a sequence is decreasing and lower bounded then it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=l>1$$

Choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $l-\epsilon>1$
Hence $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}>l-\epsilon $$ for $$n\geq m$$

Also $$a_{n+1}<\frac{a_n}{l-\epsilon}$$ for $n\geq m$

$$a_p<a_m\left(\frac{1}{l-\epsilon}\right)^{p-m}$$

Now take $p\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series $\sum a_n$. By the ration test the series converges, so that $a_n\rightarrow0$.